# Capture all dynamic form submits

Tags: javascript, forms, dom

A couple of things that I am taking account for:

- Forms can be inserted into the dom at any point in time.  A dom ready listener and iteration over `document.forms` is not an option.
- Adding this submit capturing logic is a nice to have, it should work cross browser but adding `jQuery` to make it work would be overkill.
- We are using a very heavy dom manipulation framework and the solution shouldn't hurt the overall applications performance.
- I don't want to add dom insertion listeners because they are slow and
  the framework that we use inserts items into the dom quite often.

Overriding `HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit` works when `.submit()` is programatically called but not when the user triggers a form submit through purely browser interaction.  I found that listening to the submit event works for both cases but in order to listen to the event you need a reference to each form instance.  All form instances can be obtained through `document.forms` but `document.forms` is a HTMLCollection and there isn't an api to monitor changes [MutationObservers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) only work with `Nodes` not `HTMLCollections`.  The two approaches that I believe will work seem quite messy.

1. `setInterval` can be used to monitor `document.forms` and if a new form has been added to the `HTMLCollection` add the listener to the form.
2. Monitor document mutation events and add a listener when a `form` is inserted into the dom.

Other ugly approaches that I tried that did not work:

1. Use `Object.defineProperty` for the length property of `document.forms`.
2. Override constructor of `HTMLFormElement` to run the normal construction logic and then add an event listener for `submit`.

Any tips on advice on what to do?  I am leaning towards using `setInterval` but that approach is not guaranteed to work under all scenarios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to capture forms submitted by user, you could use event delegation to body.

Then:

```
// Capture user submitted forms:
document.body.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    /* `e.target` is the form being submitted 
       Use `e.preventDefault()` to prevent submitting it */
}, false);

// Capture programmatically submitted forms:
var _submit = HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit;
HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit = function () {
    /* `this` is the form being submitted 
       Use `_submit.call(this)` to submit it */
};
```